# What happened to camera search on Google Now?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-now

It used to be under Settings, there was a Search With Camera option which would boot up the camera and allow you to take a photo which you could search with.

Since the last google now update, I can't find it.

Has it been moved to another spot or did they get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Google Goggles installed? It's required still for that feature to work in google now.

Comment: just installed it. Ah ok, well it still doesn't have it in Google Now but Google Goggles pretty much does that. That's kind of annoying, that they would take that feature and put it into its own app instead of having it integrated into Google Now

Comment: Goggles predates the Google Now experience, FYI. After you enable SEARCH FROM CAMERA, all you need to do now is take a picture with the Camera app and Google will automatically perform a search on the image clicked and display results in the notification bar.

Comment: @Sparx : yeah looks like they integrated into Google Now, then for some reason, took it out again in the latest version. The Search From Camera feature seem a bit intrusive to me. I would only want to send google images if I explicitly want to use them in a search.

Comment: Yeah I ended up removing it personally. It somehow ended up being big battery drain too